# (React + Meteor) Edit content in another div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, meteor, react-dom

I currently have this as my "index" for my Meteor app:

```
import React from 'react';

export const App = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  },
  render() {
     return <div className="app-div">
       **<Foo/>**
       **<Bar/>**
       { this.props.children }
    </div>;
  },
});
```

I am wondering if I can somehow change content of "Foo", through code in "Bar".

Essentially, "Foo" will have code like this:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="test">TEXT TO BE REPLACED</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Bar, will also have similar code:

```
export class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Code goes here to change that div "test"'s content in Foo^^^^^^
    return(
        <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I need to have some sort of code that changes the "TEXT TO BE REPLACED". Is there a way to do this somehow? Maybe with the react DOM or something? I am kind of brute forcing my way through this, so I may not know basic fundamentals, sorry

Thanks in advance

Comment: React content changing goes forward only, like parent to children not otherwise.You should use flux frameworks like redux to achieve that functionality

Comment: @saiyan So theres no way that I can somehow "look up" in the hierarchy of html tags/elements? Maybe something like parent.parent.parent.getelement('test').text = new text, or something similar in functionality to that?

Comment: No there is no way.If you are familiar with angular  `redux` is kind of similar to `services` or `factories`.

Comment: You should be able to use a Meteor [Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) variable to share state between components. `Session.set('title','foo')` and `Session.get('title')`. Whether or not that's a *desirable* pattern is another issue.

Comment: You can use the Meteor/Mongo database to do this too. If Bar updates something in the database, and Foo is displaying that item, the helpers will re-run, and React will re-render the view for you.

Answer (score 0):

In React+Meteor, communication between two siblings component should be done through their parent.

For your case, I would use a state in App component to store the content of "TEXT TO BE REPLACE", and a function inside App component to update that state content:

```
import React from 'react';

export const App = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      fooText: '',
    };
  },
  updateFooText(value) {
    this.setState({
      fooText: value,
    });
  },
  render() {
     return (
       <div className="app-div">
         <Foo text={this.state.fooText} />
         <Bar updateFooText={this.updateFooText} />
         { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  },
});

export class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="test">{this.props.text}</div>
    );
  }
}

export class Bar extends React.Component {
  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.props.updateFooText(e.target.value);
  },
  render() {
    // Code goes here to change that div "test"'s content in Foo^^^^^^
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```